# Strange behavior of image when switching between tabs in Ionic 5 tabs app

Tags: css, ionic-framework, scroll

I have an Ionic 5 tabs app.  When running ionic serve, I get the following as expected:
[image: on running ionic serve]

my home(Tab 1) SCSS file is this:

```
#container { text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

***EDIT:*** my home(Tab 1).html file is this:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true"><div id="container"><img src="../../assets/icon/favicon-128x128.png">
```

All well and good but if I click ***Tab 2*** and then click the ***home tab*** I get the following unexpected behavior where the logo is no longer centered.  Its scrolled down considerably:
[image: after coming back to home tab]

I readily admit that I am no SCSS/CSS wiz but I can not for the life of me understand why this is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: Okay, my bad.  I will attempt to do that.  I found a solution but wasn't sure it was an answer per se since I do not know why it worked... just that it did.